# Como colocar um valor do método dentro de uma ListView

Tags: java, android

Boa noite, estou criando um app que gera números aleatórios para mim, só que tive uma ideia que facilita para o usuário.... Quando ele quiser gerar mais de um bloco de números aleatórios, ele escolhe a quantidade que quer e manda gerar, e mostra os blocos de números gerados de acordo com o que o usuário escolheu....

Com gambiarra dá para fazer: crio varias textview e adapto com o switch... mas queria fazer algo certo...

criei um método **gera** que instancia a classe com a função de gerar números randômicos, e dentro do seekbar coloquei um switch para fazer esta ação de acordo com a quantidade que o usuario escolheu... mas queria mostrar dentro de uma listview. Tem como fazer isso? alguém pode me ajudar?

codigo:

```
package com.nathan.lotogera.lotogera.Fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nathan.lotogera.lotogera.Controller.NumberRandom;
import com.nathan.lotogera.lotogera.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class DuplaSena extends Fragment {

    private TextView group1, alert, group2, quantJogos;
    public Button calculate;
    public SeekBar jogos;
    private ListView lista;

    public DuplaSena() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dupla_sena, container, false);

        group1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        alert = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        group2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        quantJogos = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textjogoShow);
        jogos = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekJogos);
        lista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listateste);

        calculate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        String[] teste = new String[0];

        final ArrayAdapter<String> listagem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                teste
                );

        lista.setAdapter(listagem);

        jogos.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                switch (progress){
                    case 1:
                        gera();

                        break;

                    case 2:
                        gera();

                        break;
                }

                quantJogos.setText("reste " + progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "parou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void gera(){
        NumberRandom numberRandom = new NumberRandom();

        numberRandom.megaSena();

        String groupFirst = numberRandom.getPrimary();
        String groupSecond = numberRandom.getSecond();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criei seu vetor teste como `List<String> teste = new ArrayList<String>();`. Tente criar esse vetor como variável de classe e não local, assim poderá ser chamado no método **gera()**.

```
List<String> teste = new ArrayList<String>();

final ArrayAdapter<String> listagem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            teste
            );
```